# How to decide the suitable design pattern for an angular Application

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture, migration

I have been working on converting one Jquery based web application to Angular 5 based web Application (The application is about Electronic Billing where one can Aggregate and Pay the bills from multiple providers).

The main goal is to make product codebase more maintainable. I am not very strong in angular design patterns but I know the core concept of angular SPA (universal state management, Observable patterns, component based architecture, use of service, modular structure, Reactive Nature of Angular Framework etc) but I am wondering if there is any logical path to conclude the most suitable design pattern for this billing app.

First logical task that comes into mind is to break down the application in modules and component, and then decide the parent child relationship between them. After this step, I am getting confused about what to conclude.

Depending upon the relationship, is it possible to conclude most close pattern needed for this migration?

Edit : while researching over the web, I found this article comprehensive and gave me much needed direction.

https://bulldogjob.com/articles/539-scalable-angular-application-architecture

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are framework agnostic.   But for your app I would probably use the service layer pattern ( to communicate between the components) and a repository pattern to handle crud from angular to the backend api.    Then just make whatever your backend stack is a simple API that communicates with the database    80 % of all enterprise style apps we make follow this pattern:

Angular component => service.ts => repository => .net core api => database

But patterns aside.  Choose the right pattern for the job.   Each use case is going to be different.  I’ve only outlined what normally works for my team.

Comment: If I understand correctly, 
1) I should make sibling components which can communicate with each other using shared services (Observable) when needed
2) Put common operations to all components in service.ts
3) Use repository to finally communicate with REST APIs. But what is this repository? is it same as service.ts? Can you please elaborate this repository part?

Comment: The repository pattern is a design pattern that isolates data access behind interface abstractions. Connecting to the database and manipulating data storage objects is performed through methods provided by the interface's implementation. Consequently, there's no need for calling code to deal with database concerns, such as connections, commands, and readers [Repository pattern explained](https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/02/The-Repository-Pattern-For-Dummies.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your're looking for a way to structurize your application, taking a look at [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction) may not be a bad idea. There are even several [libraries](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux) for angular.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Is the redux pattern exclusive or it can be used with other patterns? I mean to ask that what is the single most benefit of using redux?

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusive"? It's your code, you can do anything with it. You could use redux in one place and abandon it in another. But even when always strictly followed, you can and should use other patterns but some aren't necessary anymore. About single most benefit: It gives the ability to access and persist data in a structured manner from everywhere inside you application. Besides, it is great for other developers to start coding inside your project.

Comment: Ok I got it.  I have this wrong perception about use of pattern in angular application. By exclusive I meant following Redux pattern strictly.

Comment: Yeah, then i'd suggest to always follow the redux pattern except you have a very very good reason to not. But no such reason comes to my mind...